# How to make IntelliJ run a Spring Boot App with the Maven profile it's built with?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, intellij-idea

This has been driving me crazy - I have a Spring Boot app which uses Maven as its build tool. In the POM there are various profiles set up, which point to resources in a corresponding directory within the project, so that if you build, for example, with

```
mvn clean install -PBrandADev
```

you get Brand A's Dev profile, with the corresponding application.properties and other config files, and if you build it with

```
mvn clean install -PBrandBProd
```

you get Brand B's production profile. This is important to me because it controls which CMS I'm connecting to, and thus I'm able by building as Brand B Prod to run an instance of the Prod environment in debug & see what's going wrong when there's a bug, or otherwise to build the Dev profile for the development work I'm doing, to plug into the Dev CMS.

As it's a Spring Boot app, in the resources directory for each profile we have a banner.txt file that says "Brand A - Dev" or "Brand A - QA" or whatever the brand & CMS is for that profile.

Just lately though, I'm building for a particular profile, e.g. I want Brand B's Preview-Prod environment, and I see when it starts up for its integration tests "Brand B - Preview-Prod", which is as should be expected, but then when I start it up using the Application config item in the Run/Debug configurations widget at the top of the screen, it starts up saying "Brand A - Dev"

I've tried cleaning & reinstalling the app. I've tried re-importing the maven dependencies. I've tried invalidating the cache and restarting the IDE. I've tried deselecting all the profiles and reselecting the one I need. No joy. Except, just earlier today, it worked, and then I tried to swap back to the Dev environment & it got stuck on Prod. Does anyone know what I can do to force it to use the profile it's built with? Is this a bug in IntelliJ or what?

Comment: `but then when I start it up using the Application config item in the Run/Debug configurations widget at the top of the screen, it starts up saying "Brand A - Dev"` - Do you use Spring Boot Run Configuration?

Comment: I was - as in the menu drop-down thing in the top of the IDEA screen? I was using that, and it seemed to be reliable until yesterday, and now it's behaving very randomly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the spring-boot maven plugin instead.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

This allows you to use `mvn spring-boot:run -PBrandADev` and start the spring boot application with the correct maven profile.

Comment: Fantastic - yes, this does the trick. Also I was able to combine this with @proactive-e's approach & copied the Application Spring Boot Run Configuration, putting in the -PBrandADev as a parameter, so now I have a bunch of drop-down run / debug configurations that work nice and explicitly. Thanks all!

Comment: Ugh: Addendum to that - putting the parameter on the Spring Boot Run Configuration didn't work. It just appeared to but it's just random after all. The mvn spring-boot:run -PPROFILENAME thing does work, but when I passed this on to my team one of my co-workers reported that he got errors trying to do a debug that way i.e. 
    mvn spring-boot:debug -PPROFILENAME

Answer (score 1):

A possible reason of such behaviour could be the `Run Configuration` used to start the application which builds it using default profile before starting the application. Verify `Before Launch` section of the configuration.

As a workaround, create a `Run Configuration` per profile you'd like to start, and specify `-Dspring.profiles.active=<PROFILE-NAME>` in the VM Options of the run configuration. Additionally, you could build the application using the same profile before starting it, adjust the `Before Launch` section accordingly.